# Determine the importance of new features for an exiting classification model without retraining?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

There are ways to estimate the importance of features in the model.

However, if I have a new feature and want to know whether this can help my existing classification model, what can analysis I do? Assuming retraining models with new features + old features is too computationally intensive.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could create a new model with no large computational cost that takes as input the old features, extended with the new one.

Then use the output of this new model as input to the *trained* existing model.

Then train this combination to see if the new feature improves the result.

Comment: How could you use "the output of this new model as input to the trained existing model"? The input of the trained existing model is those old features only, right?

Comment: If the new feature does not contribute any information needed for the classification *that is not already* in the old features, then the output of the new model should converge to those old features. But who knows ... It's just a thought.